# How to check why Dask is not freeing up memory on Variable overwrite

Tags: dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Having a `dask.DataFrame` which consumes around 100GB in memory::

```
ddf = client.persist(ddf)
len(ddf_c.index)
# 246652596 rows
```

```
## Running some other code like groupby/aggregate etc
```

Now I want to filter out the data by using `.loc` operator, but after running the following, the RAM consumption is 165GB:

```
ddf_c = ddf_c.loc[ddf_c.is_in_valid_set_of_combis == True]
ddf_c = client.persist(ddf_c) # Now we have 165GB RAM consumptioon
```

How can I check for open/pending/waiting futures/tasks/datasets which are preventing Dask from really overwriting the `ddf_c` `dask.DataFrame`?

This is what the info page looks liks:

```
('loc-series-b0f23c725a607fed56584d9e41e57de8', 77)     227.41 MB 
[... around 50 entries ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track dependencies in the "info" pages of the dashboard  (click the info tab at the top)

In your situation I would probly not persist until the latter step.

Comment: Ok yes, I can click through it and see some dependencies using `loc-series-{{some_id}}` and I see different memory/processing states such as `waiting`, `released`, `processing`, `memory`. But how would you find these **open dependencies** for a specific `ddf`? Can I start with some `id` from the `client` object and then digging further?